# HTML & CSS white gap above navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm still new to HTML & CSS. I've experienced a issue which I can't figure out how to fix.

There is a white gap above the navbar. Is it possible I can do it so it's attached to the top.

HTML

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
        <li><a href="mailto:enquiry@efc.ac.uk">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JOBS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NEWS AND EVENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BUISNESS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">COURSES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT EPPING FOREST COLLEGE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.navbar ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #333;
}

.navbar li {
    float: right;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #e74c3c;
}
```

Comment: and only a tip: write only "0" instead of "0px" in your css properties.

Comment: yes there is border top at .navbar class add this line in .navbar {border-top : 0px;}

Answer (score 3):

Try this css, because of the browsers default margin of the ul.

```
.navbar ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer, if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a default margin and padding from the browser so you have to do this in your css

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

A browser has some default margin and padding so you can undo this in your CSS by putting in:

```
body{
margin:0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to remove the margin of the `ul`

> The default margin is `16px`

```
ul {
  margin:0;
}
```

***[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/uetppjft/)***

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
html, body
{
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use margin: 0; inside
like this.

```
.navbar ul{margin: 0;}
```

[Check demo here](http://codepen.io/prince3339/pen/vLqaLK)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
   *{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

the problem of it is you'll need to set a margin and padding at every `div` that you make.

OR

```
  ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes there is border top at .navbar class add this line in `.navbar {border-top : 0px;}`